# Which libraries they use to draw a dynamic chart of "country’s GDP ranking history"?

Tags: charts, javascript, website, data-visualization, frontend

I would like to draw a chart like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wykaDgXoajc

Does anyone know which JavaScript libraries they use to realise this (e.g., changing year dynamically, changing GDP number smoothly)?

Is there any code snippet available on the web?

Answer (score 0):

Every one has their own logic and approaches to draw this kind of chart. 
Please refer this example to do this: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/creating-dynamic-charts/

Hope this will help you.

Thank you.